# Alias the sum of two columns in a DBIx::Class resultset

Tags: perl, alias, dbix-class

> SELECT me.id, me.date_created, me.date_updated, me.yes,
> me.name, me.description, me.currency, me.locked, me.skip,
> me.uri_part, me.user_id,
> **yes + currency as weight**
>
> FROM ideas me having ((weight < 5)) order by weight;

How can I generate that query in DBIx::Class without using literal SQL like this:

```
    my $query = $rs->search({},
    {
        '+select' => \[
            'yes + currency as weight',
        ],
        rows => 1,
        order_by => { -desc => [qw/weight name/] },
        having => {
            weight => { '<' => $self->yes + $self->currency },
        },
    });
    use Data::Dumper;
    warn Dumper($query->as_query);
```

I tried using -as, however, it seems to only be useful for working with columns generated from functions, as this:

```
'+select' =>  {
  'yes + currency', '-as' => 'weight'
}
```

generates an error

> "Odd number of elements in anonymous hash at
> /data/TGC/lib/TGC/DB/Result/Idea.pm line 105,  line 1000.
> DBIx::Class::SQLMaker::_recurse_fields(): Malformed select argument -
> too many keys in hash: SCALAR(0xbf14c40),weight"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the most idiomatic thing I can think of in SQL Abstract expression, without straining too hard:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use Modern::Perl;

use MySchema;
use Data::Dumper;

my $schema = MySchema->connect('dbi:SQLite:example.db');

my $rs = $schema->resultset('Sample')->search(
  {
     weight => { '<' => 5 },
  },
  {
    '+select' => [
        { '' => \'`me`.`yes` + `me`.`currency`', -as => 'weight' }
    ]
  }
);


say Dumper( $rs->as_query() );
```

Which is a contrived wrapping of the column names, but it does the job, sort of. Just don't know of any way to *abstract* the `+` here. But stil:

> '(SELECT me.name, me.yes, me.currency, ( me.yes + me.currency ) AS weight FROM sample me WHERE ( weight < ? ))',

Unless you are just **going for** idiomatic perl, in which case:

```
{ '' => \(join " + ", qw/`me`.`yes` `me`.`currency`/), -as => 'weight' }
```

But either way seems a little contrived considering both forms are longer than the literal string.

Also note that `weight` is referenced in **WHERE** and not **HAVING** which is because that **will** blow up on various SQL engines.

Comment: I updated the original query to fix the base SQL syntax issues.  On top of that, I think we may be running different versions of SQL::Abstract or DBIx::Class, because I don't get the same query as you do (after modifying the original with your suggested clause):

SELECT `me`.`id`, `me`.`date_created`, `me`.`date_updated`, `me`.`yes`, `me`.`name`, `me`.`description`, `me`.`currency`, `me`.`locked`, `me`.`skip`, `me`.`uri_part`, `me`.`user_id`, ( `me`.`yes + me`.`currency` ) AS `weight` FROM `ideas` `me` HAVING `weight` < ? ORDER BY `weight` DESC, `name` DESC LIMIT ?)

Comment: Are you talking about the quoting? That would be because of which "DBI driver" you have implemented. All I saying about **HAVING** is that **won't** be supported in **every** database back end. So even while it generates, that may **blow up** if you switch databases.

Comment: @perlDreamer Forgot to tag you on the comment

Comment: I only have to support MySQL.  SO ate my quotes.  If you look carefully, it is

    'me'.'yes+me'.'currency'

SQL Abstract ate the plus sign.

Comment: @perlDreamer Yes. It does that for MySQL. So quote the strings **literally** yourself. "`me`.`yes` + `me`.`currency`" Can't do anything else other than that because it is going in as **one** string literal. Well SO is going to play with the quotes, but you know what I mean. I hope

Answer (score 0):

The '+as' should be at the same level as '+select'

```
$idea = $rs->search({-and => [
    name   => { '<' => $self->name },
]},
{
    '+select' => [
        'yes + currency'
    ],
    '+as' => [qw/weight/],
    rows => 1,
    order_by => ['weight', 'name'],
    having => {
        weight => { '<' => $self->yes + $self->currency },
    },
})->single;
```

Comment: +as doesn't create `select this as that from table` syntax.

From the [ResultSet docs](http://search.cpan.org/~ribasushi/DBIx-Class-0.08270/lib/DBIx/Class/ResultSet.pm#as)

The "as" attribute has nothing to do with the SQL-side AS. See "select" for details.

Comment: @perlDreamer actually it does http://search.cpan.org/~ribasushi/DBIx-Class-0.08270/lib/DBIx/Class/Manual/Cookbook.pod#Using_database_functions_or_stored_procedures

Comment: @alex That doesn't look right. Have you looked at the SQL generated from this?

Comment: @alex, If you read right below the code example you're quoting, you'll see that is says "Note that the as attribute has absolutely nothing to do with the SQL syntax SELECT foo AS bar", and then it shows you how to control the column name.  I did take the time to try your answer, and it does not generate the right SQL syntax.

Comment: @perlDreamer The pure SQL is unrelated to the DBIx::Class result. Why you need specific SQL column name if the DBIx::Class will rename it anyway?