# Use function value from subquery in WHERE-clause + fetch it with results using DBIx::Class

Tags: sql, postgresql, perl, dbix-class

I try to build a complex query in DBIx::Class that

- prefetches a related row
- calculates an aggregate function in a subquery
- filters results according to the function value
- fetch the function value with the rows

In my application this is one of the table with the most rows. Therefor I want to do calculation and filtering in 1 query.

I tried to make a simple example by using the DBICTest from DBIx::Class’s Git repo. See https://github.com/Perl5/DBIx-Class/tree/maint/0.0828xx/t/lib/DBICTest

```perl
BEGIN { do "./t/lib/ANFANG.pm" or die( $@ || $! ) }

use strict;
use warnings;

use lib 'lib';
use DBICTest;

$ENV{DBIC_TRACE} = 1;
$ENV{DBIC_TRACE_PROFILE} = 'console';

my $schema = DBICTest->init_schema();

my $rs = $schema->resultset('CD');

my $subquery_rs = $rs->search(
    undef,
    {
        '+select' => [
            {
                '' => $rs->search_related('tracks')    # in reality I use correlate()
                  ->count_rs->as_query,
                -as => 'correlated_subquery_col'
            }
        ],
        '+as' => ['correlated_subquery_key'],
        alias => 'subquery',     # from approach number 4 and 6
    }
)->as_subselect_rs;

$subquery_rs->search(
    {
        correlated_subquery_col => { '<' => 3 },
    },
    {
        alias      => 'subquery',    # from approach number 5 and 6
        prefetch   => 'artist',
        '+columns' => { correlated_subquery_key => 'correlated_subquery_col' },
    }
)->all;
```

Run the code like this:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/Perl5/DBIx-Class.git
$ cd DBIx-Class/
$ git checkout master
$ perl test.pl # file shown above
```

(In my real project I use DBIx::Class::Helper::Correlate to sum up related values but I couldn’t use it in the example.)

The desired SQL boils down to this for the example schema:

```sql
-- pseudo code
SELECT * FROM ( -- all columns from main and related table as well as function value
    SELECT cd.*, -- main table
           artist.*, -- prefetched related table
           (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM track WHERE track.cd = cd.cdid) AS track_count -- subquery with COUNT/SUM
    FROM cds, -- main table
    JOIN artist ON artist.artistid = cd.artist -- related table
)
WHERE track_count < ?
```

I tried to come closer to a solution in these steps:

1. At first I had the problem that PostgreSQL wouldn’t let me
   reference the result from the function in the additional column but [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/132182/using-sub-query-column-in-where-clause) helped me.
   So I need to use another subquery. I found and used `ResultSet->as_subselect_rs()`
   for the first time to create that.
2. I needed to actively select the function column from the subquery in the outer `search()` call. Usually I use the `'+columns' => { result_hashref_key => 'sql_column_name' }` syntax to select
   extra columns but I found the syntax below necessary in order to define
   the column name `correlated_subquery_col`. The name needs to be
   referenced in the WHERE-clause, too. I am not aware of documentation for this
   weird syntax with empty hash key `select => [ { '' => ..., -as => ... } ]` but was inspired to try this by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22057084/alias-the-sum-of-two-columns-in-a-dbixclass-resultset).
3. Without the `alias` attribute this actually worked in the example with SQLite but in  PostgreSQL with my real schema I got the error message:

```sql
DBIx::Class::Storage::DBI::_dbh_execute(): DBI Exception: DBD::Pg::st execute failed:
 ERROR:  column reference "id" is ambiguous
LINE 1: SELECT "items"."id", "items"."purchase_list_id", "items"."va...
               ^ [for Statement "SELECT "items"."id", "items"."purchase_list_id", "items"."value", "items"."offset", "items"."unit_id", "items"."article_id", "items"."purchased", "items"."comment", "items"."servings_sum", "items"."preorder_servings" FROM (SELECT "items"."id", "items"."purchase_list_id", "items"."value", "items"."offset", "items"."unit_id", "items"."article_id", "items"."purchased", "items"."comment", ( (SELECT SUM( "dish"."servings" ) FROM "dish_ingredients" "ingredients_alias"  JOIN "dishes" "dish" ON "dish"."id" = "ingredients_alias"."dish_id" WHERE ( "ingredients_alias"."item_id" = "items"."id" )) ) AS "servings_sum", "article"."id", "article"."project_id", "article"."shop_section_id", "article"."shelf_life_days", "article"."preorder_servings", "article"."preorder_workdays", "article"."name", "article"."comment" FROM "purchase_lists" "me"  JOIN "items" "items" ON "items"."purchase_list_id" = "me"."id"  JOIN "articles" "article" ON "article"."id" = "items"."article_id" WHERE ( ( "article"."preorder_servings" IS NOT NULL AND "article"."preorder_workdays" IS NOT NULL AND "me"."project_id" = ? ) )) "items" WHERE ( "servings_sum" >= "preorder_servings" )" with ParamValues: 1='150']
```

4. Using the `alias` attribute in the subquery `search()` I tried to give the subquery distinct table aliases. That produces this SQL in SQLite:

```sql
SELECT subquery.cdid, subquery.artist, subquery.title, subquery.year, subquery.genreid, subquery.single_track, subquery.correlated_subquery_col, artist.artistid, artist.name, artist.rank, artist.charfield FROM (SELECT subquery.cdid, subquery.artist, subquery.title, subquery.year, subquery.genreid, subquery.single_track, ( (SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM cd me  JOIN track tracks ON tracks.cd = me.cdid) ) AS correlated_subquery_col FROM cd subquery) subquery  JOIN artist artist ON artist.artistid = subquery.artist WHERE ( correlated_subquery_col < ? )
```

Unfortunately not only is the subquery aliased to `subquery` for the outer query but also inside the subquery DBIC tries to SELECT from `subquery.` and JOIN using `subquery.` columns. In PostgreSQL this produces this error:

```sql
DBIx::Class::Storage::DBI::_dbh_execute(): DBI Exception: DBD::Pg::st execute failed:
 ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "subquery"
LINE 1: ...d"  JOIN "articles" "article" ON "article"."id" = "subquery"...
                                                             ^ [for Statement "SELECT "subquery"."id", "subquery"."purchase_list_id", "subquery"."value", "subquery"."offset", "subquery"."unit_id", "subquery"."article_id", "subquery"."purchased", "subquery"."comment", "subquery"."servings_sum", "subquery"."preorder_servings" FROM (SELECT "subquery"."id", "subquery"."purchase_list_id", "subquery"."value", "subquery"."offset", "subquery"."unit_id", "subquery"."article_id", "subquery"."purchased", "subquery"."comment", ( (SELECT SUM( "dish"."servings" ) FROM "dish_ingredients" "ingredients_alias"  JOIN "dishes" "dish" ON "dish"."id" = "ingredients_alias"."dish_id" WHERE ( "ingredients_alias"."item_id" = "items"."id" )) ) AS "servings_sum", "article"."id", "article"."project_id", "article"."shop_section_id", "article"."shelf_life_days", "article"."preorder_servings", "article"."preorder_workdays", "article"."name", "article"."comment" FROM "purchase_lists" "me"  JOIN "items" "items" ON "items"."purchase_list_id" = "me"."id"  JOIN "articles" "article" ON "article"."id" = "subquery"."article_id" WHERE ( ( "article"."preorder_servings" IS NOT NULL AND "article"."preorder_workdays" IS NOT NULL AND "me"."project_id" = ? ) )) "subquery" WHERE ( "servings_sum" >= "preorder_servings" )" with ParamValues: 1='150']
```

5. Alternatively I tried to use the `alias` attribute in the outer query’s `search()`. Then the alias is only used in the outer query but the subquery doesn’t get aliased at all and the columns can’t be found.

```sql
DBIx::Class::Storage::DBI::_dbh_execute(): DBI Exception: DBD::Pg::st execute failed:
 ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "subquery"
LINE 1: SELECT "subquery"."id", "subquery"."purchase_list_id", "subq...
               ^ [for Statement "SELECT "subquery"."id", "subquery"."purchase_list_id", "subquery"."value", "subquery"."offset", "subquery"."unit_id", "subquery"."article_id", "subquery"."purchased", "subquery"."comment", "subquery"."servings_sum", "subquery"."preorder_servings" FROM (SELECT "items"."id", "items"."purchase_list_id", "items"."value", "items"."offset", "items"."unit_id", "items"."article_id", "items"."purchased", "items"."comment", ( (SELECT SUM( "dish"."servings" ) FROM "dish_ingredients" "ingredients_alias"  JOIN "dishes" "dish" ON "dish"."id" = "ingredients_alias"."dish_id" WHERE ( "ingredients_alias"."item_id" = "items"."id" )) ) AS "servings_sum", "article"."id", "article"."project_id", "article"."shop_section_id", "article"."shelf_life_days", "article"."preorder_servings", "article"."preorder_workdays", "article"."name", "article"."comment" FROM "purchase_lists" "me"  JOIN "items" "items" ON "items"."purchase_list_id" = "me"."id"  JOIN "articles" "article" ON "article"."id" = "items"."article_id" WHERE ( ( "article"."preorder_servings" IS NOT NULL AND "article"."preorder_workdays" IS NOT NULL AND "me"."project_id" = ? ) )) "items" WHERE ( "servings_sum" >= "preorder_servings" )" with ParamValues: 1='150']
```

6. At last I tried setting `alias => 'subquery'` in both `search()` calls. This gives the same error message although the alias is now used in all SELECT column names. Weirdly though, DBIC still uses the default table alias `me` and writes `FROM "purchase_lists" "me"` in PostgreSQL:

```
DBIx::Class::Storage::DBI::_dbh_execute(): DBI Exception: DBD::Pg::st execute failed:
 ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "subquery"
LINE 1: ...d"  JOIN "articles" "article" ON "article"."id" = "subquery"...
                                                             ^ [for Statement "SELECT "subquery"."id", "subquery"."purchase_list_id", "subquery"."value", "subquery"."offset", "subquery"."unit_id", "subquery"."article_id", "subquery"."purchased", "subquery"."comment", "subquery"."servings_sum", "subquery"."preorder_servings" FROM (SELECT "subquery"."id", "subquery"."purchase_list_id", "subquery"."value", "subquery"."offset", "subquery"."unit_id", "subquery"."article_id", "subquery"."purchased", "subquery"."comment", ( (SELECT SUM( "dish"."servings" ) FROM "dish_ingredients" "ingredients_alias"  JOIN "dishes" "dish" ON "dish"."id" = "ingredients_alias"."dish_id" WHERE ( "ingredients_alias"."item_id" = "items"."id" )) ) AS "servings_sum", "article"."id", "article"."project_id", "article"."shop_section_id", "article"."shelf_life_days", "article"."preorder_servings", "article"."preorder_workdays", "article"."name", "article"."comment" FROM "purchase_lists" "me"  JOIN "items" "items" ON "items"."purchase_list_id" = "me"."id"  JOIN "articles" "article" ON "article"."id" = "subquery"."article_id" WHERE ( ( "article"."preorder_servings" IS NOT NULL AND "article"."preorder_workdays" IS NOT NULL AND "me"."project_id" = ? ) )) "subquery" WHERE ( "servings_sum" >= "preorder_servings" )" with ParamValues: 1='150']
```

… but `FROM cd subquery` in the SQLite example:

```sql
SELECT subquery.cdid, subquery.artist, subquery.title, subquery.year, subquery.genreid, subquery.single_track, subquery.correlated_subquery_col, artist.artistid, artist.name, artist.rank, artist.charfield FROM (
    SELECT subquery.cdid, subquery.artist, subquery.title, subquery.year, subquery.genreid, subquery.single_track, ( (
        SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM cd me  JOIN track tracks ON tracks.cd = me.cdid
    ) ) AS correlated_subquery_col
    FROM cd subquery -- uses alias here in SQLite but not in PostgreSQL
) subquery
JOIN artist artist ON artist.artistid = subquery.artist
WHERE ( correlated_subquery_col < ? )
```

**Questions:**

- How to implement my desired query with DBIC?
- I found differences between SQLite and PostgreSQL using the same DBIC syntax. Might that be a bug? I might try to further reduce the example in order to post a potential bug report to the DBIC mailing list.

If you are curious, what my real query is about: My app is for collecting recipes and making food plans. I need to fetch all purchase list items, prefetch their article and calculate a sum for each list item of how many servings require this item to be purchased. Example row: purchase list item 100kg apples is related to article apple and has a sum of 25 servings from two dishes with 10 and 15 servings each. For preordering only purchase list items which exceed a given number of servings shall be displayed.

Comment: For such a complex query I might recommend doing this directly with DBI and mapping it back your model later, but I am not a DBIC expert, so there may be a better way.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to [barubary on Mastodon who helped me find a solution](https://ieji.de/@barubary@infosec.exchange/111484937375715419).

The problem was with the `as` and `alias` keys. This is even much simpler and works:

```perl
my $rs = $schema->resultset('CD');

my $subquery_rs = $rs->search(
    undef,
    {       
        '+select' => [
            {     
                '' => $rs->search_related('tracks')    # in reality I use correlate()
                  ->count_rs->as_query,
                -as => 'correlated_subquery_col'
            },
        ],
    }
)->as_subselect_rs;

$subquery_rs->search(
    {
        correlated_subquery_col => { '<' => 3 },
    },
    {
        prefetch   => 'artist',
        '+columns' => { correlated_subquery_key => 'correlated_subquery_col' },
    }
)->all;
```

It produces this SQL:

```sql
SELECT me.cdid, me.artist, me.title, me.year, me.genreid, me.single_track, me.correlated_subquery_col, artist.artistid, artist.name, artist.rank, artist.charfield 
  FROM ( 
    SELECT me.cdid, me.artist, me.title, me.year, me.genreid, me.single_track, ( 
        SELECT COUNT( * ) 
          FROM cd me 
          JOIN track tracks 
            ON tracks.cd = me.cdid
       ) AS correlated_subquery_col 
      FROM cd me
   ) me 
  JOIN artist artist 
    ON artist.artistid = me.artist 
WHERE correlated_subquery_col < '3'
```